# Why does Screen Fill not Remove Blit in my Pygame Program?

Tags: python, pygame

I am developing a Python program which uses Pygame. I cannot clear the screen entirely as using screen.fill still results in lingering text. My code:

```py
while True:
    scene0()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            screen.fill("White")
            pygame.display.flip()
```

The `scene0()` code:

```py
def scene0():
        into_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 200)
        intro_surf = into_font.render('Game Name', False, 'Black').convert()
        intro_rect = intro_surf.get_rect(center=(600, 300))
        txt_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 90)
        text_surf = txt_font.render('Press Space to Start', False, "Black").convert()
        text_rect = text_surf.get_rect(center=(600,420))

        screen.blit(intro_surf, intro_rect)
        screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            if exit_button.draw(screen):
                run = exit()
```

The scene 0:
[Scene 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqtEu.png)

After using screen fill:
[After screen fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp21a.png)

Comment: Please read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to mention what you want to achieve, what problem you are facing and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because, `screen.fill()` clears the screen, but, in the next iteration of the `while` loop, the `scene0()` function blits everything on the screen again. You can create a condition and then call the `scene0()` function. Example code:

```py
screen_status = "active"

while True:
    if screen_status == "active":
        scene0()
    elif screen_status == "blank":
        screen.fill("White")
        pygame.display.flip()    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            screen_status = "blank"
```

In the above code, initially the `screen_status` variable is set to `active`, so the `scene0()` function is called. However, when the spacebar is pressed, `screen_status` is set to `blank`. So, the screen is cleared.

If you want to blit everything again, you can set `screen_status` to `active` again.